# jQuery dialog box opne .php file

Tags: php, jquery, dialog

It's a simple JQ, when I click on a link(in file a.php) I want to open a dialog box and load a different php(file b.php) into the dialog box

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `open` option to load content on the dialog open. For example:

```
// a.php
    $(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({open: function() {
            //display correct dialog content
            $("#dialog").load("b.php");}});
    });
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/ND62K/).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
$('#dialog_link').click(function(){
    $("#dialog").fadeIn(500).load('b.php');
})
```